# QML timer combined with transition

Tags: animation, timer, qml, transition

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {

id: rec
property int img_in:2
property int img_out:3

Image {
   id: imgout
   source:  "pics/"+img_out+".jpg"
   opacity: 1
   anchors.fill: parent
}

Image {
   id: imgin
   source:  "pics/"+img_in+".jpg"
   opacity: 0
   anchors.fill: imgout
  }

Timer {
    interval: 5000
    repeat: true
    running: true
    onTriggered: {
        img_in = img_in+1
        img_out = img_out+1
        anim.running = true;
     }
}

states: State {
    name: "state1"
    PropertyChanges { target: imgout; opacity: 0}
    PropertyChanges { target: imgin; opacity: 1}
}

SequentialAnimation {
    id: anim
    NumberAnimation { target: imgin; properties: "opacity"; easing.type: Easing.InOutQuad; duration: 1500 }
    NumberAnimation { target: imgout; properties: "opacity"; easing.type: Easing.InOutQuad; duration: 1500 }
}
```

}

I would like to know if the problem is in opacity or in pics number change. Pics do change (suddenly) but there is no animation. Inside onTriggered I have tried to use these options: states, SequentialAnimation plus transition. No help.

Comment: The "`rec`" state never changes, so the `opacity` property don't change to. When you do `anim.running = true` there's nothing to do on opacity.

Comment: Can you explain more what you're exactly trying to accomplish with imgin and imgout? For example, do you want imgin to fade in and imgout to fade out when the time expires?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I took your code and customized it a bit. It basically starts at pics/1.jpg fades it out while fading pics/2.jpg in, then continues to the next images. You should be able to use it and change it to suit your needs.

Importantly there is no need to do this with `States` rather use `Behaviour` on the `Image` elements `opacity`

Hope this answers your question! It does make for a nice slideshow!

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
    id: rec

    // [1] First image is to be display is pics/1.jpg,
    // followed by 2.jpg, 3.jpg, etc...
    property int currentIndex: 1
    property int nextIndex: 2

    // [2] When swapping the image sources we need
    // to block the animation behaviour.
    // By default turn it on.
    property bool allowBehaviour: true

    // [3] When the 'rec' is loaded
    // set the current image to fade out
    // and the next image to fade in.
    Component.onCompleted: {
        currentImage.opacity = 0;
        nextImage.opacity = 1;
    }

    Image {
        id: currentImage
        source:  "pics/" + currentIndex + ".jpg"
        opacity: 1
        anchors.fill: parent

        // [4] Here we define that whenever we change the
        // opacity we want it to animate. Notice the enable
        // is tied to `allowBehaviour`
        Behavior on opacity {
            enabled: allowBehaviour
            NumberAnimation { easing.type: Easing.InOutQuad; duration: 2500 }
        }
    }

    Image {
        id: nextImage
        source:  "pics/" + nextIndex + ".jpg"
        opacity: 0
        anchors.fill: currentImage

        // [5] See [4] above.
        Behavior on opacity {
            enabled: allowBehaviour
            NumberAnimation { easing.type: Easing.InOutQuad; duration: 2500 }
        }
    }

    Timer {
        interval: 2500
        repeat: true
        running: true

        onTriggered: {
            // [6] Block the Behaviour animation.
            allowBehaviour = false;

            // [7] Advance the indices.
            currentIndex = nextIndex;
            ++nextIndex;

            // [8] This is key, set the current
            // image to visible and the next
            // image to invisible. This happens
            // instantly as the Behaviour is off.
            currentImage.opacity = 1;
            nextImage.opacity = 0;

            // [9] Turn the behaviour so the
            // opacity change at [10] will
            // cause an animation.
            allowBehaviour = true;

            // [10] Like [3] set the current
            // image to fade out and the
            // next image to fade in.
            currentImage.opacity = 0;
            nextImage.opacity = 1;
        }
    }
}
```